# npm start & install are broken, loading.js: 583 terminal error every time

Tags: reactjs, terminal

I must have broken something somewhere, but I have no idea where or how to fix it.

Everything was working find this morning, but when I tried to use my terminal to run npm start or npm install later I was given the same error.

```
Matthews-MacBook-Air-3:materialize matt$ npm start
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:153:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
```

This happened after I tried to fix a different error not allowing me to npm start the app as well. I tried downloading yarn, which failed, and then this new error popped up. I did this because the terminal said that it could fix the original problem I was having, but it seems to have magnified it lol.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your node_modules folder and package-lock.json and then run npm install again.

Comment: Did that, it didn't work. It's happening in all of my react folders, not just 1.

Comment: hmm maybe check the version numbers on the package that's throwing the error and see if there was an update.

Comment: I think it's more of a terminal issue, since it doesn't allow me to start any of my previous projects and give me the same exact error.

Comment: Seems like a npm issue then. Try to update npm: npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: @MattBrody have you tried clearing cache before trying to update npm? npm cache clean -f

Comment: I guess your best bet is to reinstall npm then

Comment: When I check npm -v, I get the error too. I'll look into uninstalling it, but I'm not sure how I can if it throws an error whenever it's run.

Comment: You can uninstall using rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm then reinstall it

Comment: matt$ -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
-bash: -rf: command not found

Comment: rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

Comment: Awesome, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, simply reinstall the latest version of node from its website, http://nodejs.org. 
After installation, run *npm start*